# ICollection acting as IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I am accessing the `Keys` of an `OrderedDictionary`:

[image]

Why does it say this?:

> Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable

I thought anything more concrete than an `IEnumerable` (eg `ICollection`, `IList` etc) are already enumerated?

Comment: enumerate means it will loop over the results to fetch them all to display them in the debug window

Comment: "I thought anything more concrete than an IEnumerable (eg ICollection)" are you sure that ICollection is more concrete than IEnumerable, Or are you just making that assumption based off the default implentations that you've naturally encounter e.g Entityframeworks ICollections which are backed by HashSet etc

Comment: an Interface doesn't make anything more concrete at all... e.g Array Implements IList `Array : IList` however if you call .Add on an array you'll get an exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<T>` implements both `IList<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`.  Logically, it cannot be both already enumerated and not already enumerated.  The interfaces only define a contract through which you can interact with the object.

What matters is the underlying type implementing the interface.  LINQ expression trees use deferred execution, with an object structure representing the pending LINQ operation(s).  That underlying type, which implements the interfaces in the question, knows whether it represents such a deferred operation.

In this case, the underlying object does use deferred execution, so VS prompts you.

Comment: how does it "know" that is has already been enumerated? I think that's a feature of the debugger, it executes it once and remembers the result. Afaik an IEnumerable has no memory and will always execute its "deferred operation" on every Enumeration.

Comment: @Charles, look into `GetEnumerator`

Comment: @Charles Depends on the type.  There's no one answer.  But your statement "IEnumerable has no memory" has no meaning, as `IEnumerable` is not an implementation, it's an interface.  An implementation of that interface can have "memory".