# Unable to use ICollection.ToList()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.5, icollection

I am trying to call `ToList()` here:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;

namespace CSVStuff
{
    public static class CSVContentGenerator
    {
        public static string GetContent(IOrderedDictionary headingsPropertiesMapping)
        {
            var propertyNames = headingsPropertiesMapping.Keys.ToList(); //ICollection does not contain a definition for ToList()
            //var propertyNames = new List<object>(headingsPropertiesMapping.Keys); //Cannot convert from ICollection to int
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Why are these not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ICollection acting as IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59313510/icollection-acting-as-ienumerable)

Comment: @Jawad This is a completely different question. This is asking why an ICollection, which would usually allow ToList() to be called, is not working in this situation. The other one was asking why it was enumerated.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave `Enumerable.ToList()` requires a generic: IEnumerable<T> or ICollection<T>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var propertyNames = headingsPropertiesMapping.Keys.Cast<T>().ToList();
```

and type `T` is the type of dictionary keys.

Comment: i think ordered dictionary is old? that's why it doesn't have a generic type. .NET Framework 2.0

Comment: @Charles Yes, I think so. but I don't have seen any document confirming that it is deprecated.